# Cannot serialize sealed trait in Akka using jackson-cbor

Tags: scala, jackson, akka

I am trying to adapt the [Akka distrubuted workers sample](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.6/akka-sample-distributed-workers-scala) project. Basically, I want to create more `Work` items, which will be sent from the `FrontEnd` and then computed in a distributed manner by the `WorkExecutor`, and then get the result back to the `FrontEnd`.

My problem is that I want to extend `Work` in a way that I can pass through other types of work (which extend `Work`) in a rather generic way (e.g., `WorkManager` should only deal with `Work`).

```
sealed trait Work extends CborSerializable {
  def workId: String

  def job: Int
}

case class MyWorkItem(workId: String, job: Int) extends Work
```

Unfortunately, jackson-cbor is not able to serialize `Work`.

```
4163 [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] ERROR org.test.worker.WorkManager$ - Supervisor StopSupervisor saw failure: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [2]. PersistenceId [master], due to: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [2]. PersistenceId [master], due to: Cannot construct instance of `org.test.worker.Work` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (byte[])"�dwork�fworkIdx$f031c8c6-6b7e-4e63-9beb-e97330eea35ecjob��"; line: -1, column: 6] (through reference chain: org.test.worker.WorkState$WorkAccepted["work"])
akka.persistence.typed.internal.JournalFailureException: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [2]. PersistenceId [master], due to: Exception during recovery. Last known sequence number [2]. PersistenceId [master], due to: Cannot construct instance of `org.test.worker.Work` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (byte[])"�dwork�fworkIdx$f031c8c6-6b7e-4e63-9beb-e97330eea35ecjob��"; line: -1, column: 6] (through reference chain: org.test.worker.WorkState$WorkAccepted["work"])
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onRecoveryFailure(ReplayingEvents.scala:220)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onJournalResponse(ReplayingEvents.scala:153)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onMessage(ReplayingEvents.scala:91)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.ReplayingEvents.onMessage(ReplayingEvents.scala:66)
    at akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AbstractBehavior.receive(AbstractBehavior.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$$anon$2.apply(InterceptorImpl.scala:57)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.EventSourcedBehaviorImpl$$anon$1.aroundReceive(EventSourcedBehaviorImpl.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl.receive(InterceptorImpl.scala:85)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$$anon$2.apply(InterceptorImpl.scala:57)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.SimpleSupervisor.aroundReceive(Supervision.scala:124)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl.receive(InterceptorImpl.scala:85)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$$anon$2.apply(InterceptorImpl.scala:57)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl.receive(InterceptorImpl.scala:87)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl$$anon$2.apply(InterceptorImpl.scala:57)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.SimpleSupervisor.aroundReceive(Supervision.scala:124)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.InterceptorImpl.receive(InterceptorImpl.scala:85)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpret(Behavior.scala:274)
    at akka.actor.typed.Behavior$.interpretMessage(Behavior.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.handleMessage(ActorAdapter.scala:129)
    at akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter.ActorAdapter.aroundReceive(ActorAdapter.scala:106)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:577)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is

> Cannot construct instance of `org.test.worker.Work`

This is because `Work` is an abstract class and therefore cannot be constructed.

The answer is also in the error message:

> abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Note that the fact it is `sealed` is not relevant, the problem is that it is a `trait` not a concrete `class`.

Comment: Yes, I know. The point is, I don't understand how the distributed worker should be implemented in Akka, when there are multiple types of work items. Ideally, I would have only one implementation of `WorkManager`, `WorkState`, `Worker`, and only deal in `WorkExecutor` with the work-item-specific code.

Comment: Your code is not working because of this serialization issue. If you fix that, the rest of the code will probably work.

Comment: I will then try to create a custom deserializer for this trait to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR

```
final case class Zoo(primaryAttraction: Animal) extends MySerializable

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
  Array(
    new JsonSubTypes.Type(value = classOf[Lion], name = "lion"),
    new JsonSubTypes.Type(value = classOf[Elephant], name = "elephant")))
sealed trait Animal

final case class Lion(name: String) extends Animal

final case class Elephant(name: String, age: Int) extends Animal
```

The above is a copypaste of this link https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/serialization-jackson.html#polymorphic-types

**Explanation**

Assume that you have a method that accepts instance of `Work` in your case, but the problem is that you could have many implementations of `Work` trait, so Akka (or rather Jackson) would not know to which implementation of `Work` it would need to map incoming JSON. By using `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` you instruct Jackson to add `type` property to serialized JSON, which then will be used to deserialize JSON back into your concrete class.

You could argue that your trait is sealed and Jackson/Akka could figure out that you have only one implementation and just use it, but I guess this is not implemented and maybe not so easy to implement.

This is a tricky one because this error would only appear if a messages is sent from one node to another in the cluster, and would not appear if messages is sent between actors on the same node.